# Mover tabla de solo lectura con handtool

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera mover una tabla grande con handtool como la imagen de este ejemplo

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/touchScroller.html

Pero con una tabla grande html, en horizontal y vertical, hay algún plugin para hacer eso?

Answer (score 0):

Espero que sea esto lo que estas buscando.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('Drop.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```